# Textbox to DIV with jQuery - Enter key to create line break?

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I've found this Fiddle which does exactly what I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/56/ with the exception that line breaks in the textbox aren't replicated in the DIV. Could anybody point me in the right direction with code that detects these line breaks and carries them over? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/57/

Answer (score 1):

Check the update in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/58/

Use pre tag instead of div , it works fine